# xargs: how to "describe" output by input arguments

Tags: shell, xargs

I have the following `xargs` command line:

```
$ gethosts |xargs -L1 -I% rx % some-command
```

where `gethosts` is a script to get a list of host addresses, and `rx` is a script to execute certain command on remote host.  The output might be:

```
output 1
output 2
...
```

What I want is the command can output its argument:

```
host1,output1
host2,output2
...
```

i.e., I would like to know, for each output line, which host generated that ouput.

Comment: Your `rx` obviously gets the name of the host as the first parameter. Just modifie rx so that it adds the hostname to its output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you have to use option command in *xargs* "-c" and run sh for example to specify wich interpretor used for this command.

To print the host (without newline) the *printf* command will be used.

The final result looks like this command line :

```
gethost|xargs -L1 -I% sh -c 'printf "%, " && rx % some-command'
```